# Sum of Eulers phi function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Given that $p$ is a prime number, how would one calculate the sum: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\phi (p^k)}  $$
I know from Euler's phi function that if $p$ is a prime number then:
$${\phi (p^k)} = {p^{k-1}}(p-1) = p^k-p^{k-1} $$
but here I'm stuck. any clues or help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you written this out for, say, $p = 3, n = 4$? If so, you can show your work by clicking "edit" below your question. Doing this example might help you notice a pattern.

Comment: Render your sum for a few small values of $n$.  Note how terms cancel. Then identify the general case to prove.  Oh, and maybe have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Do you know what is a telescopic sum?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\phi (p^k)}=1+ (p-1)+(p^2-p)+(p^3-p^2)+\dots+(p^n-p^{n-1})$

Answer (score 6):

As you noted, what we're interested in is really 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (p^k - p^{k-1}). $$

Writing it out, we can see that it is a telescoping sum: 
$$(p^n - p^{n-1}) + (p^{n-1} - p^{n-2}) + \dots + (p - 1) + 1.$$

Comment: thank you, that makes it clear. so the sum would be just p then? 
I'm thinking if we only have the terms (p-1) +1 left, wouldn't that leave us with just p?

Comment: @Inves The sum is just $p^n$ since everything cancels. And yes, in that case we‘d get just $p$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \phi (p^k) = \sum_{k=0}^np^{k-1}(p-1) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^np^{k-1}(p-1) $$
$$\  = 1+(p-1)+(p^2-p)+...... (p^k-p^{k-1})+ ...... (p^n-p^{n-1})$$
which is a **telescopic sum** Therefore, it simplifies to $$\ p^n $$
And we are done :-)